# How to delete old audio interfaces

Tags: audio

I used to have WavTap and Airparrot but their audio interfaces are still straying in my other audio interfaces, and I would like to delete them.

How can I do this? I tried Audio / MIDI configuration but can't click the (-) sign to delete them.

*Example image:*

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would follow the recommendations of the WavTap developer and the Airparrot developer on how to uninstall their extensions.

But there are almost certainly files related to WavTap and Airparrot in the Extensions folder of the Library folder of the startup disk:

/Library/Extensions/

… which you can delete and then reboot in order to get rid of WavTap and Airparrot.

There may also be files at:

/System/Library/Extensions

… but be very careful in there because if you delete the wrong thing you could cause your system not to be able to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thorough answer for uninstalling WavTap quickly:

1. Open a terminal and clone the official WavTap project:

`git clone https://github.com/pje/WavTap`

2. cd into the directory (`cd WavTap`)
3. Run `sudo make uninstall` to remove all drivers and traces of WavTap
4. You can then remove the WavTap source directory.